# How long does it take to run a OpenCV DFT function on android

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv

Hi I am running DFT function from OpenCV on Android (Galaxy S4) running 4.4.2 but it is running quite slow. It takes around 800-1050 milliseconds to run [this implementation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/discrete_fourier_transform/discrete_fourier_transform.html) from OpenCV example. Is it quite normal? and is there any way to speed it. Also I think the size of image is 1080x1920 pixels.

Comment: Without knowing anything else, that doesn't sound unreasonable. 1080x1920 is a large image for a phone, and DFT is not a simple algorithm.

Comment: @Aurelius Thanks, so a possible way to run it in real time would be to decrease the image size.

Comment: Yes. In image processing, that is almost always the first step to increasing performance.